# Redux Form, Dynamic name form implicate re registeredFields

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a list and I try to create form for each item to submit them separately, each row is add dynamically. I use `compose()` to create each name of form dynamically, like this :

```
return {
    formName: ownProps.form
}
```

And I pass the form name like this in my child component (item of list), list arrive from the reducer :

```
list.map((item, index) => (
    <RowAuthorizations form={`${formName}[${index}]`} onSubmit={this.submitRowAuthorization} />
))
```

When i try to refresh my list fields without selected value from the reducer :

```
tenant.users.filter((x) => x.id !== action.payload.id)
```

**Values of the field has been deleted but registeredFields reappear** when my component re render the list without the deleted value.

When I add the field :

[image: Add the Field :]

When I remove the field :

[image: Remove the field]

Comment: Remove field in the reducer ? the reducer is not supposed to mutate anything !

Comment: The reducer only filter list to remove selected Item, after that my Component re render the updated list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem :

You need to add a nested object and add **destroyOnUnmount: true** (Defaults to true if you change it to false).
registeredField overrided each field when it was already mounted that's why my field has doesn't unregistered.

If you want to create a list and submit each row independently (each row is a form) you need to add a dynamic name to the form with mapStateToProps (dynamic name passed from the container) and recovered by an intermediate component like this :

```
 return {
    formName: ownProps.form
}
```

This formName need to be passed has a prop to each child (Form Row):

```
{   list.map((item, index) => {
        return <RowAuthorizations form={`${formName}[${index}].${name}`} onSubmit={this.submitRowAuthorization} />
    })
}
```

name is the sub object which contain registeredField, values,... so you have **user[0].user.values** unlike that **user[0].values**

If you use formReducer.plugin({}) and you want to manage form from your reducer for this case follow this steps.

Let me know, if i'm right.